# Kubectl annotate a Helm chart with Terraform

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm

I need to annotate a Helm template with Terraform, and then install them, also with Terraform (installing is very simple).

Actually I use the command below.

`helm template my-chart -n kube-system --skip-tests my-charts/my-chart --version="1.0.0" --set propertyOne="value",propertyTwo="value" | kubectl -n kube-system annotate --overwrite meta.helm.sh/release-name=my-chart meta.helm.sh/release-namespace=kube-system -f -`

And then

`helm upgrade --install my-chart -n kube-system .......`

I could easily use the `helm_template` [data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/data-sources/template) and then loop over the manifests, but I do not see how to run the *kubectl annotate* command.